# Java swing JTextField dissapears after adding a button to BorderLayout.SOUTH

Tags: java, swing

I add a JTextField to my game in the bottom left corner using a nested BorderLayout inside my main panel's BorderLayout.SOUTH. This works fine, but then when I add a button to go right next to it, my JTextField dissapears. Can someone please help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class BlackjackGUI{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel, panelLeft, panelBottom;
    private JButton newGameBtn, dealBtn, hitBtn, standBtn;
    private JLabel placeBetLbl, playerMoneyLbl;
    private JLabel playerCard1Lbl, playerCard2Lbl, playerCard3Lbl,
                   playerCard4Lbl, playerCard5Lbl, playerCard6Lbl, playerCard7Lbl;
    private JLabel dealerCard1Lbl, dealerCard2Lbl, dealerCard3Lbl, dealerCard4Lbl,
                   dealerCard5Lbl, dealerCard6Lbl, dealerCard7Lbl;  
    private JLabel playerCardValueLbl, dealerCardValueLbl;
    private JLabel spacer1, spacer2;
    private JTextField betInputBox;

    public BlackjackGUI(){
        createForm();

        addTextField();
        addButtons();
        addLabels();


        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createForm() {
        frame = new JFrame("Blackjack");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1200,800);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Color c = new Color(0, 100, 0);
        panel.setBackground(c);


        panelLeft = new JPanel();
        Color panelLeftBG = new Color (23, 25, 100);
        panelLeft.setBackground(panelLeftBG);
        panel.add(panelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);

        panelBottom = new JPanel();
        Color panelBottomBG = new Color (56, 12, 10);
        panelBottom.setBackground(panelBottomBG);
        panelBottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

    public void addButtons() {

        newGameBtn = new JButton("New Game");

        panelLeft.add(newGameBtn, BorderLayout.WEST);
        newGameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

        dealBtn = new JButton("Deal");
        dealBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100, 50));
        panelBottom.add(dealBtn, BorderLayout.WEST);
        newGameBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

    }

    public void addTextField() {

        betInputBox = new JTextField("£25.00");
        betInputBox.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        betInputBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        betInputBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175,50));
        panelBottom.add(betInputBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    public void addLabels() {

        placeBetLbl = new JLabel("Place your bets!");
        placeBetLbl.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        panelBottom.add(placeBetLbl);

        playerMoneyLbl = new JLabel("£2,500");
        playerMoneyLbl.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.PLAIN, 35));

        panelBottom.add(playerMoneyLbl, BorderLayout.EAST);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BlackjackGUI();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) javadoc:

> Each region may contain no more than one component, and is identified
>   by a corresponding constant: `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, `WEST`, and
>   `CENTER`.

Your are first adding the text field and then the button to the same region (`WEST`), thus button just replaces the text field.

To solve the issue you can use `FlowLayout` for the `panelBottom`:

```
panelBottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```